# Sign pdf with pkcs#11 using a java application

Tags: java, pdf, pkcs#11

How to sign pdf file with pkcs#11 using a java application? Is it possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible. Since Java 5, the JDK has been shipping with a PKCS#11 Provider. Please bear in mind that PKCS#11 only specifies the API to perform such operations. You still need to plug in an implementation to do the actual signing.

This guide will give you a pretty good description on how it works: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for the answer!!